# Como passar o valor de uma variável em PHP em um lugar fixo?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Boa noite senhores estou me aventurando no mundo do PHP e me deparei com um problema que ainda não consegui resolver.

Fiz uma conexão em PHP que conecta em um servidor TELNET e me retorna os valores lidos em uma variavel dentro de um While, com isso eu uso um echo para imprimir a menssagem na tela para acompanhar o conteudo da mensagem.

```
   while ($line = fgets($socket,7170)){
    $line = trim($line);
    echo $line."<br>";
}
```

algo assim, porém o resultado é que ele gera uma linha nova com a resposta.

Eu gostaria de saber uma maneira de imprimir essa variável sempre no mesmo local.

Como se fosse um campo dizendo " STATUS: $VALOR DA VARIAVEL AQUI"
para que sempre que mudasse o valor atualizasse ali e não criar um novo echo.

Comment: Como isso é atualizado?

Answer (score 0):

Existe duas maneiras de se fazer isso.

Primeiro você tirando a tag `<br />` que assim evitaria que o seu loop fizesse que o valor pulasse de linha, porém, se você quer os valores todos na mesma variável tu poderia está fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
$line = "";
while ($line = fgets($socket,7170))
{
    $line .= trim($line);
}

echo $line;
```

Comment: não sei porque mas não imprimiu os valores nessa estrutura, se eu colocar o echo dentro do while, ele imprime sempre que muda porém, fica em sequência é como se ficasse $line$line$line$line$line$line$line$line$line$line$line$line$line$line$line(o valor da variável) na página. O que eu quero saber é como o valor sobrescrever o valor impresso anteriormente.

Comment: Se você utilizar ```=``` você reatribui o valor na variavel, porém, quando você utiliza ```.=``` você concatena o valor na varialve.

Comment: a questão do .= eu entendi agora, obrigado por compartilhar comigo essa informação.

O ponto agora é que esse while executa constantemente recebendo o status do meu servidor.

só que ao colocar como está no código, não mostra informação nenhuma. 

A minha ideia é que como se fosse um html tivesse um campo com status e ali mudasse sempre com o servidor.

Comment: Eu entendi, mas a resposta foi a solução da sua pergunta? Se sim, por favor marque-a como a solução para ajudar outros usuários também.